# SegFault when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, segmentation-fault, rvm

For some reason two versions of Ruby are being picked up when I run my application:

```
[edarroyo:~/Development/sample_app]$ rails server

/Users/edarroyo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/pg-0.14.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

How can I stop my application from picking these two versions?

Answer (score 4):

1) make sure you install ruby using gcc-4.2 - it will prevent random fails which happen when you compile ruby with clang/llvm

2) make sure you use ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

I have added the default switch - so the ruby is used for every new shell session.

Comment: GNU GCC version 4.2, it is last version of GNU GCC supported by Apple, they switched to LLVM, but Ruby is not yet ready for LLVM (clang) so gcc-4.2 is required for ruby to compile/work properly.

Comment: how do I go about installing it, or verify that I have it currently?

Comment: this is where `rvm requirements` gets helpful - just run it and follow the text